# HTML issues with header displaying

Tags: html, css

**URL**: [test.getfamo.us](http://test.getfamo.us)

**Issue**: the drop down menu does not work (hover over any link to see), as I have the main box covering it.

I was trying to code the site without using percentages for height, as I heard its bad and my site was displaying poorly on other monitors so I changed it all to px. Anyway in order to do the main box I used this CSS

```
#content #main {
position: absolute;
top: 70px; 
bottom: 15px; 
width:100%;
```

So it did not cover my header or footer.
Issue being that with my Header, this is the CSS

```
#content #header {
height: 70px;
width: 100%;
}
```

I want it to be like this though so it can work on all screen sizes with the main box automatically generating its size, however I obviously want my drop downs visible so I am at a crossroads.

So how am I able to fix this?
Also if you need any more info my CSS is available: http://test.getfamo.us/css/

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Addd z-index to ul.

```
ul li ul {
    box-shadow: none;
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 48px;
    transition: opacity 0.2s ease 0s;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 150px;
    z-index: 50;
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot man, such a quick response and exactly what I was looking for. I signed up for stackoverflow less than 5 minutes ago and I already have my first question answered! So impressed, I cant accept this answer for another 8 minutes but thanks very much will accept it asap! :)